# Weird JavaScript bug in Chromium based browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium

For a school exercise, I'm trying to increase the width of a button using Javascript.

This is my code:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(button.offsetWidth);
  button.style.width = button.offsetWidth + 1 + "px";
});
```

```html
<button>Press me!</button>
```

[For some reason, the width stops increasing after 3 clicks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edTFt.png) This only happens in Chromium based browsers (Chrome, Edge, Brave). What makes this even weirder is that the code runs fine on my other laptop running the exact same versions of Chrome and Edge. In Firefox and IE9, it also works fine. I've tried cleaning my cache, and even installed a new browser (Vivaldi), which has the same problem. I am running Windows 10 version 1909 build 18363.1256. For Chrome I'm on version 87.0.4280.88, Brave, version 87.0.664.66, and Edge, version 87.0.664.66.

Comment: I'm on chrome and what you say isn't reproducible. `Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: I can't reproduce, here nor in JSFiddle, in Opera nor in Chrome

Comment: Huh, I can repro(also `Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)` on Windows).

Comment: I'm on same version of Chrome as GetSet (macOS Big Sur) and cannot reproduce. Cannot reproduce on Edge (Version 87.0.664.66 (Official build) (64-bit)) - Big Sur

Comment: Is SuperStormer the only one running Windows?

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 64 Bit Ultimate

Comment: windows 10 build 19042, specifically

Comment: Possibly some "weird" win 10 behavior on preventing button clicks

Comment: Use a debugger, set a break point, let us know if the event is no longer firing. Should probably file a bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: @GetSet the button click handler is firing, its just that the console.log keeps outputting the same thing

Comment: Console log may be "grouped". Does the button get bigger on right side with each click?

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue in `Brave (Version 1.18.75 Chromium: 87.0.4280.101 (Official Build) (x86_64))` and `Chrome (Version 88.0.4324.50 (Official Build) beta (x86_64))`. The button still grows after 3 clicks.

Comment: sample pen: https://codepen.io/SuperStormer/pen/oNzdVOV
console output: https://imgur.com/a/lHLF4s2

Could it be a weird quirk due to fractional widths and rounding?

Comment: It works fine on my other laptop, which is running the same build of Windows 10, Chrome, Edge and Brave... Weird.

Comment: @SuperStormer I think you nailed it indeed. I can now reproduce with the browser zoom set to 125%, on macOs BigSur. Definitely rounding issues. OP, you could use getBoundingClientRect to get a high precision value.

Comment: Can confirm it works fine when i use another zoom percentage.

Comment: Wow that is weird. 125% works to break this code on my browser too. As in reproducible at that zoom level. One would think a pixel is a pixel at any zoom level

Comment: @GetSet yes, but a `px` is not a pixel. It's a very weird unit that does change even relatively depending on the expected distance between the eyes and the monitor... https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#reference-pixel

Comment: As you had confirmed that `getBoundingClientRect` fixes this issue, I suggest you post the solution as an answer to this question. If you think this issue needs to be fixed in the Chromium browser engine then I suggest you post the issue [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list). Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/F7idAcq still getting rounding issues with `getBoundingClientRect`. Issues are gone again when using a different zoom percentage.

Comment: @RichardSwinkels but it doesn't stop the function from working (increment at each click).  It's just that you are still logging the rounded `.offsetWidth`

Comment: @Kaiido Oops my bad, you're right. I was still logging `.offsetWidth` indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the function getBoundingClientRect() fixes the issue.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(button.getBoundingClientRect().width);
  button.style.width = button.getBoundingClientRect().width + 1 + "px";
});
```

```html
<button>Press me!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.